# How to change the icon size in a Kivy FileChooserIconView

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I added a FileChooserIconView to my Kivy application. I want the icons to be bigger i just dont know how.

```
FileChooserIconView:
        id: kv_file_manager_icon
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.25}
        size_hint: 0.5,0.4
        icon_size: 200,200
```

[Screenshot of the Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWd4e.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is no predefined way to adjust the size of the icons. In the `style.kv` file (installed with kivy) there is a template rule `[FileIconEntry@Widget]` that defines the entry including the icon size, which is set to `size: '48dp', '48dp'`. You can make your own modified version of this template rule and adjust the size of the icon (the `Image` in that kv rule). Then use `Builder` to load your modified rule. You will likely need to make several other changes to get it to look correctly.